# NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath only works for absolute paths

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsfilemanager

I have a bunch of customer images (named [code].png) in a folder, but some customers do not have images, so I'd like to display a placeholder.

I'm checking the existence of the image [code].png, and if it exists I display that one, else I display the placeholder.  However, fileExistsAtPath *always* returns false, even for images that exist.

```
NSFileManager *m    = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",code];
if ([m fileExistsAtPath:imagePath])
    self.detailViewController.imageFrame.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",code]];
else
    self.detailViewController.imageFrame.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customer_large.png"];
```

This always displays customer_large.

However, if I change the imagePath to an absolute path to the image *and leave the displayed image as a relative filename*, the boolean works correctly, *and the image displayed works as well*.

This proves that the filename I am checking for does exist, as the image displays, but I'm obviously missing something in terms of fileExistsAtPath as it returns false when the program has proven the file to exist.

Comment: In the project root alongside all of my classes/headers, etc. Their location is set to "relative to group" and their displayed filename underneath that option is simply [code].png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the image is stored in the project, and not the documents directory, I would not use NSFileManager at all.

Instead, use [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE_FILENAME"] and see if it returns nil. If it does, then use the placeholder.

Here is a code snippet:

```
UIImage *possibleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE_FILENAME"];
if (possibleImage) {
   self.detailViewController.imageFrame.image = possibleImage;
} else {
   self.detailViewController.imageFrame.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customer_large.png"];
}
```

Comment: This is a simple solution and less verbose than my current method.  I'll accept once the appropriate time passes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your file is stored in the documents directory?? if so, get the path to the documents directory first via this:

```
NSString *destPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    destPath = [destPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",nameOfImage]];
```

This check if that file exists. Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

As it stands `imagePath` is only really the name of the image. Give this a try:

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:code ofType:@"png"];
```

Comment: this would work if it were in the documents directory, its in the project itself.

Comment: @Matthew That's what the code I've posted is for... Mashups solution is how you access the documents directory.

Comment: agreed, but in the comments he is looking for something in the project directory.

Comment: @Matthew Exactly, my code gets the path of a file in the projects directory, not the documents directory.